# Como utilizar str_replace em aspas simples sem remover as que são necessárias?

Tags: php, mysql, string

Estou mexendo em um banco de dados de um amigo o qual teve alguns dados inseridos errados ou meio confusos ou sou eu que estou dificultando.

> Ex: Mariana "Gurizinha's"

Esse exemplo foi salvo no banco da seguinte maneira: `\'Gurizinha\'s\'`

Para exibir no website dele eu tentei criar uma função a qual substitui o caractere inicial por um " e o final também por ".

O Certo seria pegar um texto que foi salvo dessa forma e que possui 100 palavras ou mais e corrigir exibindo: `"Gurizinha's"`  ao invés de `\'Gurizinha\'s\'`. 
Ai minha cabeça deu um nó pois se eu usar `str_replace` ele vai pegar todo o texto e o que tiver \' vai mudar para " então se for palavras que precisem Are's ele vai substituir por `".`

```php
function rt_especial($valor) {
  $i = 0;
  $palavras = explode(' ', $valor);

  foreach($palavras as $Arr) {
    $i++;
    $novotexto = stripcslashes($Arr);
    $i2 = 0;
    $palavras2 = explode("'", $novotexto);

    foreach($palavras2 as $Arr2) {
      $i2++;
    }

    for($i3 = 0; $i3 <= $i2; $i3++) {
      $str = '"';
      $str .= $palavras2[$i3];
    }
  }

  echo substr($string, -1);
  $novotexto = join(' ', $novotexto);

  return $novotexto;
}
```

**Código que insere os dados no banco MySQL:**

```
function db_executa($tabela, $dados, $acao = 'insert', $parametros = '') {
    reset($dados);
    if (strtolower($acao) == 'insert') {
      $consulta = 'insert into ' . $tabela . ' (';
      while (list($coluna, ) = each($dados)) $consulta .= $coluna . ', ';
      $consulta = substr($consulta, 0, -2) . ') values (';

  reset($dados);
  while (list(, $valor) = each($dados)) {
    switch ((string)$valor) {
      case 'now()':
        $consulta .= 'now(), ';
        break;
      case 'null':
        $consulta .= 'null, ';
        break;
      default:
        $consulta .= '\'' . db_entrada($valor) . '\', ';
        break;
    }
  }
  $consulta = substr($consulta, 0, -2) . ')';

} elseif (strtolower($acao) == 'update') {
  $consulta = 'update ' . $tabela . ' set ';

  reset($dados);
  while (list($coluna, $valor) = each($dados)) {
    switch ((string)$valor) {
      case 'now()':
        $consulta .= $coluna . ' = now(), ';
        break;
      case 'null':
        $consulta .= $coluna .= ' = null, ';
        break;
      default:
            $consulta .= $coluna . ' = \'' . db_entrada($valor) . '\', ';
            break;
        }
      }
      $consulta = substr($consulta, 0, -2) . ' where ' . $parametros;
    }
    return db_consulta($consulta);
  }
```

**Resolução de parte do problema:**
Não é uma maneira bonita e muito menos certa, porem foi a que consegui para resolver.

```
function rt_especial($valor){

        $string = $valor;
        $separa = explode(" ", $string); // quebra a string nos espaços
        $count = count($separa); // quantidade de separações

        $arrayok = array();



        for($i=0; $i<= $count; $i++)
        {
            // Pego toda palavra que começa com \' e substituo por "
            $string2 = ereg_replace("^([/\'])", '"',$separa[$i]);
            $string3 = str_replace("\',", '",', $string2);
            $string4 = str_replace("\',", '",', $string3);

            $string5 = ereg_replace('^([/""])', '"',$string4);
            $string6 = ereg_replace('([/""])$', '"',$string5);

            //Pego toda palavra que termina com \' e substituo por "
            $string = ereg_replace("([/\'])$", '"',$string6);
            $string7 = str_replace('"\'', '"', $string);
            $string8 = str_replace("\'\"", '"', $string7);
            $string9 = str_replace('\"', '"', $string8);


            $arrayok[$i] = $string9;

        }

        $ccp = implode(' ', $arrayok);

        return $ccp;
    }
```

Comment: Porque foi salvo no banco desta maneira `\'Gurizinha\'s\'`? qual foi o problema com o banco? extremamente não recomendo fazer uma gambi dessas porém se for preciso podemos ajudar... mas com certeza seria melhor arrumar o problema do banco ao invés de criar uma função dessas.

Comment: Ele usou um editor de texto javascript (JavaScript Swing) configurado incorretamente e o mesmo está fazendo isso com todo o texto inserido. Sendo que ele já tem mais de 1200 ID'S no banco.

Comment: Veja a configuração do Javascript Swing, e nos informe, pois dependendo, um editor de texto simples pode reverter isto.

Comment: Irei postar uma reposta contendo o código responsável por gravar no banco. O erro deve estar nele e não no editor. Perdão.

Comment: Os dados gravados são código javascript? Dá pra postar mais exemplos? O texto sempre começa **e** termina com aspas? Porque as primeiras aspas são **necessárias** e as demais não? Precisamos de um meio determinístico para saber quais aspas são "necessária" e quais não.

Comment: Realmente, deve ser nele mesmo :) achei estranho um editor de texto fazer isto...

Comment: @user Não inclua uma resposta, edite a pergunta.

Comment: esse é o código o qual os dados passam por ele ao clicar em salvar. o mesmo grava um texto como o de um blog que pode ou não conter HTML.
 `default:
            $consulta .= '\'' . db_entrada($valor) . '\', ';
            break;`

Comment: Acredito que o certo seria: `default: $consulta .= "'".db_entrada($valor)."'",'; break;`

Comment: Poderia postar o código completo para gravar?

Comment: Como sou novato, o stackoverflow não está me permitindo postar o código inteiro nem criar uma nova reposta.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e inseri o código que insere no banco.

Comment: Isto parece o tipo de problemas que as [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.magicquotes.php) causam.

Comment: Pergunta editada.

Answer (score 2):

No caso a sua pergunta não e nem voltado para PHP, mas sim MySQL.

Mas vamos lá:

Execute a query substituindo o nome da sua_tabela e sua_coluna

```
UPDATE sua_tabela
SET sua_coluna = REPLACE(sua_coluna, "\\'", '"')
WHERE sua_coluna LIKE "%\'%"
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma alternativa é selecionar os registros que deseja corrigir.

```
SELECT 

campo,
 ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(campo)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( campo, '\'', '') ) 
        ) / LENGTH('\'')        
    ) AS count

FROM

`regexp`

HAVING (
ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(campo)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( campo, '\'', '') ) 
        ) / LENGTH('\'')        
    )
) % 2 = 1
```

Nesse exemplo, a consulta retornará todos que possuírem single quote (') e a soma de suas ocorrências por row, sendo que quantidade de ocorrências deve ser número ímpar.

Qual a lógica em fazer isso?

Se existir números ímpares, provavelmente há ocorrências como \'Gurizinha\'s\'.

Com isso, eliminaria a necessidade em olhar uma boa parte dos resultados. 
Para todos os outros resultados com soma resultante em pares, apenas aplique um replace geral, trocando o single quote escapado por um double quote sem o caracter de escape.

Ainda assim não resolverá 100%, mas ao menos terá uma lista de todos os IDs dos rows que precisam ser corrigidos.

Há outras formas com REGEXP, porém, não há como usar REGEXP com REPLACE. Teria que usar um UDF. Mas acho que pode resolver de forma mais simples sem precisar de UDFs.

Comment: Muito boa Lógica.
Vou tentar aplicar estudando UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Procure sobre expressões regulares com PHP, não sou experiente ainda com elas, mas acredito que o exemplo abaixo resolve seu problema:

```
<?php
    function ModificarTXT($str)
    {
        // Pego toda palavra que começa com \' e substituo por "
        $string = ereg_replace("^([/\'])", '"',$str);

        //Pego toda palavra que termina com \' e substituo por "
        $string = ereg_replace("([/\'])$", '"',$string);
        return $string;
    }

    echo ModificarTXT("\'Gurizinha\'s\'"); // Teste da funcao
?>
```

Comment: Acredito que o problema não estaria em retirar as aspas simples, porém o autor está com dificuldades para expressar o problema, leia os comentários da pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado.
já fez um efeito diferente. o resultado foi o seguinte: `\'Valentine\'s Day\"`

Comment: Muito obrigado. Usei parte do seu código para criar um função que resolvesse parte do meu problema.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na sua conexão com o banco.

Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) que suas informações serão armazenadas exatamente da forma que passou, sem ter que remover ou substituir caracteres especiais, aspas, etc. E quando você recuperar, estará da mesma maneira que inseriu. [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) também aceita declarações parametrizadas (Preparement Statement) que vai lhe proteger de injeções SQL.

Para conectar:

```
// Dados da conexão
$host = 'localhost';
$port = '3306';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '123456';
$dbname = 'meubanco'

// Configuração para garantir a codificação correta caso esteja usando utf8
$config = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");

// Realiza a conexão
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass, $config);
```

Exemplo de INSERT parametrizado:

```
// Recebe variáveis
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];

// Define a query usando '?' no lugar das variáveis
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (codigo, nome) VALUES (?,?)";

// Prepara
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

// Seta os parametros definidos como '?' na query de acordo com a ordem
$stmt->bindValue(1, $codigo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);

// Executa query
$stmt->execute();

// Pega o total de linhas afetadas
$total = $stmt->rowCount();

// Verifica se inseriu
if( $total > 0 )
    echo "Inseriu!";
else
    echo "Não Inseriu!";
```

Exemplo de SELECT parametrizado:

```
// Recebe variáveis
$codigo_minimo = $_POST['codigo_minimo'];

// Define a query usando '?' no lugar das variáveis
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE codigo > ?)";

// Prepara
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

// Seta os parametros definidos como '?' na query de acordo com a ordem
$stmt->bindValue(1, $codigo_minimo, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Executa query
$stmt->execute();

// Muda de acesso as colunas para o modo pelo nome
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Usando fetchAll você pega todos resultados em um array
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

var_dump($result);
```

var_dump($result) iria imprimir algo assim:

```
array (size=3)
   0 => array (size=2)
       'codigo' => 1
       'nome' => "bla bla bla"
   1 => array (size=2)
       'codigo' => 2
       'nome' => "ble ble ble"
   2 => array (size=2)
       'codigo' => 3
       'nome' => "blu blu blu"
```

Para desconectar:

```
// basta setar como NULL
unset($pdo);
```

Para mais informações sobre como utilizar o [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php), acesse [este link](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Opa, muito bom. Obrigado. irei levar um tempo para adaptar o sistema do mesmo para PDO. Mais já dei inicio. Assim que adaptar o mesmo completo para PDO posto o resultado aqui.

Comment: Faça a adaptação por módulos. Crie uma classe de conexão em PDO. Escolha uma classe, a mais simples para começar, e mude-a. Após isso, sempre que puder modifique uma classe de persistência e vá mudando. :)

Comment: Preciso primeiramente aprender como funciona para poder saber aplicar. O material que tenho ainda são poucos. Mais já estou correndo atrás.

Answer (score 1):

Use uma expressão regular para substituir ' por " no início e final de palavras inteiras:

```
preg_replace_callback('/(?<=\s|\t|\r|\n| )(\'.+\')(?=\s|\t|\r|\n|\.|,| )/muU', function($match) {
    return '"' . substr($match[0], 1, -1) . '"';
}, $x);
```

Você pode usar [esta função](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) (udf) para substituír todos os registros que já estão no banco de dados:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '/(?<=\s|\t|\r|\n| )\'(?=.*\'[\s\t\r\n\., ])/', '"');
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '/(?<=[\s|\t|\r|\n| ]\'.*)\'(?=[\s\t\r\n\., ])/', '"');
```

Ou criar um script para selecionar e atualizar todas as colunas:

```
$rows = $dbh->query("SELECT id, col FROM tabela")->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tabela SET col = ? WHERE id = ?");
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $str = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=\s|\t|\r|\n| )(\'.+\')(?=\s|\t|\r|\n|\.|,| )/muU', function($match) {
       return '"' . substr($match[0], 1, -1) . '"';
    }, $row['col']);
    if($str == $row['col']) continue;
    $sth->execute(array( $str, $row['id'] ));
    $sth->closeCursor();
}
```

Comment: Opa, muito bom. Obrigado. irei levar um tempo para adaptar o sistema do mesmo para PDO. Mais já dei inicio. Assim que adaptar o mesmo completo para PDO posto o resultado aqui.